# Wordpress - trailing slash removal

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I can't remove the trailing slash from homepage link `example.com/blog/`.
I tried it from `.htaccess` as well as from site config.

```
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

It is working from permalinks, and all categories and posts being without trailing slash.
But homepage still has it and is really annoying and not good for my SEO.

** blog is a subdirectory

also treid to define htaccess like the following:

```
Options -Indexes
DirectorySlash Off

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog$ /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following in .htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

Since `/blog` is (I assume) a physical directory then mod_dir will ordinarily append the trailing slash in order to "fix" the URL.

However, whether this will now work *without* the trailing slash is another matter, since you will now need to *internally rewrite* the request to include the trailing slash.

**UPDATE:** To remove the "file list" when accessing `/blog` you should add the following directive to the top of your `.htaccess` file (this is a good idea anyway, regardless of the current problem):

```
Options -Indexes
```

To make this "work" without the trailing slash, you will need to *manually* internally rewrite the request to include the trailing slash (since that is strictly the "correct" URL since this is a physical directory), or take it one step further (and avoid mod_dir requesting the `DirectoryIndex`) and rewrite to `/blog/index.php` - which I assume is the required filename, being WordPress.

In the .htaccess file in the document root, add the following before any existing mod_rewrite directives:

```
RewriteRule ^blog$ /blog/index.php [L]
```

Comment: yes this is a physical directory, -  your solution is not working for me
it is show me the file list :
Index of /blog     

and the site working only with trailing slash 
 
any other idea? thx very much

Comment: Presumably WordPress is installed in the `/blog` subdirectory? I've updated my answer.

Comment: I tried that - not working   -please see my post i edited it with the htaccess file

Comment: I am getting "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /blog on this server."
And permissions are ok

Comment: @MladenJanjetovic You'll get a 403 Forbidden if you have disabled directory indexes and there is no directory index document present in that directory (this is not a file permissions issue). However, as noted above, if you are actively _removing_ the trailing slash on physical directories then you need to internally rewrite the request to "fix" the URL (by appending a trailing slash), otherwise, server behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to Settings -> General -> WordPress Address (URL) and remove the trailing slash.